# Search & LazyLoad can't keep up w/ typing speed?

Tags: javascript, jstree

So, all of the code works quite well. A database a queried, the node/parent IDs are lazily passed to jsTree, and, if one types a term into the search bar—a similar process goes on, but the nodes passed to jsTree are those returned by another SQL query (using something like `SELECT nodeID FROM table WHERE name LIKE %searchTerm%`).

There's only one problem:

If I type too quickly into the search bar, the results get all mixed up with one another. If I type slowly (I'd estimate 2 letters a second max), everything works well. Any faster and everything is blurred together. (That is, if I'm searching for names which contain the term "test", and type this quickly, I'll get names that contain "t", "te", "tes", and "test" instead of just names that contain "test".)

Anyone have this problem before? Is there some "wait until ready" function I should be using?

Comment: You might want to look into your SQL logic. When you do "<code>name LIKE %searchTerm%</code>" you will be doing full table scan which is slow. You might want to cache the strings in you app and do a quick regex match to avoid running into long wait times in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you to do the 'Timeout' workaround. Basically, you create a SetTimeout function with a delay of 200-400 miliseconds and launch your lazyload ajax there. Every inputbox.change event restarts the time. See example in pseudo-javascript:

```
$('#your-input').keydown(function(){
    if(ajaxTimer != undefined) {
        clearTimeout(ajaxTimer);
    }
    ajaxTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({...}).done(function() {...}
    },400);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a throttle on the typing input, basically guarantees that a function will be called a maxmimum of once every X seconds. Sure you could write your own however there is a great library out there already.

check it out if you're interested http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/